# application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: not called with CloudKit

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios8, cloudkit

I've been trying to register for push notification using CloudKit, but so far it does not work. More specifically, neither UIApplication delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

or

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

is not called. However, the sample code from this year's WWDC works. I wonder if I'm missing something here, or is it really a bug from Apple's side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's technical guidelines on APNS, sometimes we need to turn off the app's notifications and then turn back on again. I did that, and it works again.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you explain how you "turn off the app's notifications and then turn back on again"?

Comment: Go to Settings -> Your App -> Push Notification On/Off switch.

Answer (score 1):

In your application properties, Capabilities, you have to enable Background Modes, Remote notification.